# Searching blogposts returns 404

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, blog

I've got a blog on a intranet site, based on the blog template.
Whenever I search for a particular post, it returns the correct post, but not the correct url.
The link returned from search:

```
http://intranet/SomeSite/Lists/posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=99
```

This does not work. However, if i change ViewPost to just Post it works, like so:

```
http://intranet/SomeSite/Lists/posts/Post.aspx?ID=99
```

So, what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewPost.aspx redirect to similar kind of this URL

http://topsite/Subsite/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=709a6bf9%2D4faa%2D4b07%2D8da1%2D4a973ed6e95e&ID=10&Web=923799df%2D7bd8%2D4bf9%2D9978%2D1f56dfac8284

So check Relevant List Id and Web Id.

Comment: Thanks, Your previous answer did it for me, duplicating post.aspx and renaming the duplicate, viewpost.aspx.